# Perl regex - need to ignore first two instances of a character

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract the message attribute from the following string (i.e. I want to extract *The String "test" appears 4 times in the file.*).

```
severity="warning" message="The String "test" appears 4 times in the file." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.MultipleStringLiteralsCheck"
```

I've tried using the regular expression `message="([^"]*)"` but this stops at the first " that appears. `The String` is getting returned in this case.

Is there a way to ignore the inner quotes within the message attribute and capture the entire attribute?

Comment: Like [`message="(.*?)"(?=\s+\w+=|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/lH8eN4/2)?

Comment: The regexp is fine, the string is invalid, if it contains double quote characters inside a string delimited by double quote characters they must be escaped otherwise it is anyone's guess what the true interpretation is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution will break if "`=`" characters start appearing in the attribute values.

Comment: Only if there are alphanumerics right before them. Surely it can  break with such input.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew and neuhaus for the help. Wicktor's solution works which will help me for now. I'll see if I can get the format of the string fixed in the meantime.

Comment: I have posted my suggestion with clearly stated assumptions then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If we can assume that the *key* always consists of alphanumerics or underscore symbols (`\w+`) and is followed with `=` and the vlaues do not contain that pattern**, you can use a lazy quantifier with a dot `.*?` and check the trailing boundary with a positive lookehead. Thus, **as a quick-and-dirty once-time fix**, you can use

```
message="(.*?)"(?=\s+\w+=|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lH8eN4/2)

Note that `.` does not match newline symbols by default, you will need a `/s` modifier.

**The input you have needs fixing by all means.**

Answer (score 1):

If the attributes are always in this order, i.e. `source` follows `message`, you might try to make it a bit more robust

```
message="(.*?)"\s+source="
```

This will break of course, if `source=` occurs in the message.

Comment: Or if the order of keys is not the same, or "source" key is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This solution keeps fetching characters from the string until a new label like `source=` is encountered. All parameter values are stored in hash `%params`, so the value for `message` is just `$params{message}`

I've used `Data::Dump` only to display the complete hash contents once the string has been parsed

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $str = 'severity="warning" message="The String "test" appears 4 times in the file." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.MultipleStringLiteralsCheck"';

my %params;

while ( $str =~ / (\w+) \s* = \s* " ( (?: . (?! \w+ \s* = ) )* ) " /gsx ) {
    $params{$1} = $2;
}

say $params{message};

use Data::Dump;
dd \%params;
```

#### output

```
The String "test" appears 4 times in the file.
{
  message  => "The String \"test\" appears 4 times in the file.",
  severity => "warning",
  source   => "com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.MultipleStringLiteralsCheck",
}
```